# WriteFile() always succeeds when used for COM device, even if no device is attached, is this normal?

Tags: c++, winapi, io, serial-port

I open the COM port ("COM1") with CreateFile and then use WriteFile to send data to device. And as the title says, WriteFile always succeeds and even returns correct number of bytes in *lpNumberOfBytesWritten, as if it had really delivered the bytes, even though the device is not connected!! Is this normal behavior or did I messed up something hardly?

P.S.: I'm having problems with talking to my device so I'd like to know if this is normal or not.

Comment: I honestly don't know the answer to your question, but since you are writing to a port and not to a device it doesn't strike me as odd that it returns successfuly even if no device is attached.

Comment: I don't think WriteFile is synchronous on COM ports, you have to use overlapped I/O to find out whether the write was really successful.

Comment: When I use ReadFile, it just times out (I use overlapped IO with finite timeout). But WriteFile succeeds as if there was a device. So how can I detect if there is any device at given port then? (besides receiving the data from device via ReadFile which would be the true indication)...

Comment: I use overlapped I/O. WriteFile returns ERROR_IO_PENDING but then WaitForSingleObject returns WAIT_OBJECT_0, and GetOverlappedResult returns the number of bytes written (which is equal to number of bytes passed). I believe this is the successful write scenario right?

Comment: Do you have any kind of flow control enabled?

Comment: Hardware flow control is on afaik. This is how I compose DCB:

' // Create blank DCB:

 DCB newComDcb;
 ZeroMemory(&newComDcb, sizeof(DCB));

 // Set non-zero values:

 newComDcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB); // Structure size.
 newComDcb.BaudRate = dwBaudRate; // Baud rate.
 newComDcb.fBinary = 1; // Binary transfer mode - ON.
 newComDcb.ByteSize = 8; // Data bits - 8.
 newComDcb.fDtrControl = newComDcb.fRtsControl = 1; // Hardware flow control - ON.'

Comment: But the cable I use has only 3 pins connected, so I believe hardware flow control can't be used with that device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial port is a fairly simple device, and I don't think it has much notion of whether or not a device is attached. So, naturally, you can always write characters to the serial port and the bits will just harmlessly ooze out of the connector.